# What's different QRemoteObjectRegistryHost and QRemoteObjectHost?

Tags: qt, qt5, qtremoteobjects

I am new to learn `QRemoteObjects`, i understand usage of [Direct Connection with a Dynamic Replica](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/remoteobjects-example-dynamic-replica.html).But i don't understand [Connections to Remote Nodes using a Registry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/remoteobjects-example-registry.html) mechanism.I got confused the relationship between `QRemoteObjectRegistryHost`, `QRemoteObjectHost`, `QRemoteObjectNode` and `QRemoteObjectReplica`, can anyone give me simple explanation?

**In Registry method**
server use code like this

```py
regNode = QRemoteObjectRegistryHost(QUrl('local:registry'))
srcNode = QRemoteObjectHost(QUrl('local:replica'), QUrl('local:registry'))
#is there will create two Local Socket  server?
```

client use

```py
repNode = QRemoteObjectNode(QUrl('local:registry'))
```

What's the difference `QUrl('local:registry')` and `QUrl('local:replica')`?
And I think `QRemoteObjectHost(QUrl('local:replica'), QUrl('local:registry'))` is redundant in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example you provide the advantage is not observed and therefore you see it redundant.

In some applications there is a need to have several sources and it would be redundant for the replicas to have to connect to each source, so the task of QRemoteObjectRegistryHost is to have a connection point for several sources and that the replicas are connected through it.

For example, the following scheme shows its use:

```
 ┌-------------------┐                ┌-------------------┐
 | QRemoteObjectHost |                | QRemoteObjectHost |
 └--------┬----------┘                └-------┬-----------┘
          |                                   |
          |                                   |
     ┌----┴-----------------------------------┴----┐ 
     |          QRemoteObjectRegistryHost          |
     └--┬-------------------┬-----------------┬----┘
        |                   |                 |
        |                   |                 |
┌-------┴----- ---┐ ┌-------┴---------┐ ┌-----┴------- ---┐
|QRemoteObjectNode| |QRemoteObjectNode| |QRemoteObjectNode|
└-----------------┘ └-----------------┘ └-----------------┘
```

Multiple nodes can be registered through `QRemoteObjectHost`, and the `QRemoteObjectHost` is registered in the `QRemoteObjectRegistryHost` so that any `QRemoteObjectNode` can obtain replicas of the `QRemoteObjectHost` nodes through `QRemoteObjectRegistryHost`.

To illustrate the functionality I created the following example:

```
├── register.py
├── replica.py
└── source.py
```

**register.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    regNode = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectRegistryHost(
        QtCore.QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
    )

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**replica.py**

```py
from functools import partial
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    node = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectNode(QtCore.QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557"))

    replicas = []

    def on_remoteObjectAdded(info):
        name, url = info
        print("object added", name, url)
        replica = node.acquireDynamic(name)

        wrapper = partial(on_initialized, replica, name)
        replica.initialized.connect(wrapper)
        replicas.append(replica)

    node.registry().remoteObjectAdded.connect(on_remoteObjectAdded)

    def on_initialized(replica, name):
        wrapper = partial(print, name)
        replica.dataChanged.connect(wrapper)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**source.py**

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtRemoteObjects


class Node(QtCore.QObject):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

    parser = QtCore.QCommandLineParser()
    parser.addPositionalArgument("url", "Host URL different to tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
    parser.addPositionalArgument("name", "Name of node")
    parser.process(app)
    args = parser.positionalArguments()

    if len(args) != 2:
        print("only url and name is required")
        sys.exit(-1)

    url, name = args

    if QtCore.QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557") == QtCore.QUrl(url):
        print("url different tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
        sys.exit(-1)

    node = Node()
    srcNode = QtRemoteObjects.QRemoteObjectHost(
        QtCore.QUrl(url), QtCore.QUrl("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
    )
    srcNode.enableRemoting(node, name)

    def on_timeout():
        data = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString()
        node.dataChanged.emit(data)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Then run the following commands on different CMDs/terminals:

```
python register.py
```

```
python replica.py
```

```
python source.py tcp://127.0.0.1:5558 node1
```

```
python source.py tcp://127.0.0.1:5559 node2
```

And in the CMD/terminal console of replica.py you will see the following:

```
# ...
node1 Tue Jan 7 22:32:09 2020
node2 Tue Jan 7 22:32:09 2020
node1 Tue Jan 7 22:32:10 2020
node2 Tue Jan 7 22:32:10 2020
# ...
```

Comment: Is there any tool or method to write `console` markdown style as you had writed upon? It may useful when i don't want to paste picture to illustrate something.

Comment: @jie No, if there is one let me know, I did everything manually.